# Hadoop - get results from output files after reduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Given a job with map and reduce phases, I can see that the output folder contains files named like "part-r-00000".

If I need to post-process these files on application level, do I need to iterate over all files in output folder in natural naming order (part-r-00000, part-r-00001,part-r-00002 ...) in order to get job results?

Or I can use some hadoop helper file reader, which will allow me to get some "iterator" and handle file switching for me (when file part-r-00000 is completely read, continue from file part-r-00001)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In mapreduce you specify an output folder, the only thing it will contain will be part-r files (which is the output of a reduce task) and a _SUCCESS file (which is empty). So i think if you want to do postprocessing you only need to set the output dir of job1 as the input dir for job 2.

Now there might be some requirements for your postprocessor which can be addressed, is it for example important to process the output files in order?

Or if you just want to process the files locally then it all depends on the outputformat of your mapreduce job, this will tell you how the part-r files are structured. Then you can simple use standard i/o i guess.

Comment: I need to get these files onto another host and transform/insert content into database. I can't do that insert on stage of reduce because cluster doesn't have any access to database.

Answer (score 9):

You can use getmerge command of Hadoop File System(FS) shell:

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /mapreduce/job/output/dir/ /your/local/output/file.txt
```

Comment: @jdevelop: you can use copyMerge method https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use Hadoop [FileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) to do the iteration from your application of the part-r-xxxxx files.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path("hdfs://hostname:port/joboutputpath"));
for (int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
    fs.open(status[i].getPath())));
}
```

You can also look into [ChainMapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainMapper.html)/ChainReducer.

Comment: I actually was looking for some built-in implementation for this functionality in Hadoop.

Comment: Why not use from FileSystem [copyToLocal](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#copyToLocalFile%28boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29) itself if you want it in you local filesystem or may be [FileUtils](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html), where you have several methods to try?

Comment: In this way I have to deal with couple of files. Ideally I want to specify HDFS path and record reader, and get iterator of records without worrying about how many files were created by reducer.

Comment: Have you checked [this method](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#copyMerge%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.String%29) in Hadoop FileUtils?

Comment: I don't want to copy all files from HDFS to local storage, one of reasons is that resulting file will be too big to fit in local storage.

Comment: Yup, that's correct! But you also said in one of your comments that you need to move the file to a different host for uploading to a database. So, how are you thinking to do that then? And, your cluster nodes don't have the database access as you have already mentioned.

Comment: I never said that I need to move the file to different host. I need to iterate over the files one by one, read records from the file and that's it. The only thing which seems to be missing in Hadoop is to provide some reader over couple of files, to read data from all of them without merging/copying entire file set.

Comment: Got ya! Will [Har help](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop_archives.html) in any ways? You can then provide as in input: har:///user/zoo/foo.har. But I have no idea whether the ordering will be maintained as you want. And, you just want to post process the files in order and that can be any application not necessarily Hadoop, where the the files will inevitably be processed currently even if they are merged or not?